# Sending ETH or Tokens from the command line to be integrated in a PHP script

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, php, command-line

I'm relatively new to using ETH on the command line. Do I use Geth or Parity? All I want to do is be able to send some ETH or Tokens from my eth private key. Which way is the best way to do it? I plan to integrate this into my php application, so I don't want to download the entire Ethereum blockchain. What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Parity so couldn't really tell. Geth is somewhat easy to use.

After you have decided on the client you have to decide on the node to use. Node relays your commands to the blockchain and keeps the blockchain state. You can either run your own - but you don't have to download the whole blockchain as different clients have different lighter synchronization modes (such as Geth's light and fast mode) which download only a small part of the blockchain.

If you don't want to run your own node you can use an external service provider, such as Infura, which offers access to an already running node.

Comment: I guess I will use Geth, what is a good tutorial on how to install it ? or do I just download it to my ubuntu server and just run the command ?

Comment: Sorry, can't really recommend tutorials as I've never read any. Just googled for what I need.